# Hiding type parameters that are implementation details

Tags: java, type-parameter, information-hiding

I have a class that has some type parameters that are not implementation details, and some that are.

What's the best way to deal with type parameters that should not be part of the public API without resorting to unchecked casts?

I have a class is created by a builder which picks the right helpers.  In my case, a helper knows how to do bulk reads/writes between buffer-like objects.

```
/**
 * @param <T> a type parameter that end users of PublicClass cannot ignore.
 * @param <X> has a specific relationship to T, but
 *     is an artifact of how PublicClass is implemented.
 */
public class PublicClass<T> {
  // This constructor is called from a builder.
  // The builder just returns
  //     new PublicClass<>(aHelper, someMutableState)
  // <X> is inferred from the choice of parameters.      
  <X> PublicClass(
      Helper<T, X> helper,
      StatefulInternalObject<T, X> someMutableState) {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

So there's a public class and a public builder, and some package-private implementation detail classes.

I don't want to expose `<X>` to clients, but my helper and my stateful objects need to interact in ways that depend on `<X>`, and the helper converts types that use `<T>` into types that use `<X>`, so using unchecked casts involving `<X>` would make PublicClass's implementation brittle.

I can create yet another hidden class that has both sets of type parameters and then make my public API just forward to that class:

```
public class PublicCLass<T> {
  private final class TypedImpl<T, ?> typeSafeImplementation;

  <X> PublicClass(
      Helper<T, X> helper,
      StatefulInternalObject<T, X> someMutableState) {
    typeSafeImplementation = new TypedImpl<>(
        helper, someMutableState);
  }

  // Public API just forwards to an internal
  // implementation class.
  public SomeType0 someMethod(SomeType1 x) {
    return typeSafeImplementation(x);
  }

  ...
}
```

Is there any better way that doesn't require these shallow forwarding methods?

Comment: I finding it hard to understand the question. When you say "I have a class is created by a builder", do you mean "I have a class whose *instances* are created by builder", or that the class is created by an automated code generator that you call "builder"? Also, what do you mean by "not expose X"? X is just a parameter, not a concrete class. It's not known by the class's users (except the builder). Do you mean you don't want to expose the fact the one of the constructors uses a Helper? And also, that constructor seems to be package-private access. Isn't that enough?

Comment: If `<X>` is considered implementation detail from the perspective of `PublicCLass<T>`, then maybe you should create `PublicHelper<T> extends Helper<T, X>` and `PublicStatefulInternalObject<T> extends StatefulInternalObject<T, X>` and use these two classes instead of `Helper` and `StatefulInternalObject` in the public API of `PublicClass`. That will hide `X` from users of `PublicClass`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, Yes re builder creating instances.


By "not expose X", I want clients to be able to write `PublicClass<T>` instead of `PublicClass<T, ?>` or `PublicClass<T, SomethingElse>` partly because it's more work for the clients, and partly because I'd like to have the flexibility to do away with `<X>` entirely without having to do a major version bump and ask clients to rewrite types.

Comment: @ernest_k, How would creating two public subclasses that hide `X` help type-check interactions between those classes that depend on `X`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel Good point. I see that it won't help, unless perhaps you further create another class with a static `X` and containing both types as fields. This perhaps means that there will be such a class for each concrete `X`, which would be ridiculous until we consider that `X` is information to be given by the API's client (which we want to prevent). I'm trying to say that if the client has to supply two `X`-bound parameters, then they must know about `X` for type safety, unless we create a type that hides `X` from them (one `X` at a time) while guaranteeing that `X` will mean the same thing

Comment: @ernest_k, The `TypedImpl` does kind of bundle both types as fields.  Having a class for each concrete `<X>` might not be ridiculous for the case I'm working on.  I was hoping for a more general solution, but the problem in front of me involves 2 public type parameters and 2 internal type parameters from a small set including `<Byte, byte[], ByteBuffer, ReadOnlyByteBuffer>`.